# Shortcut if function with some and & or in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an if with many conditions and & or.
Is there any short cut to obtain the same result but in a cleaner way?

```
if x == "1" and y == "1" or f == "1" and y == "2" or  x == "2" and y == "2" or x == "2" and y == "1":
    value="Valid"
```

Comment: Maybe `x in "12" and y in "12": ...`

Comment: Is that one `f == "1"` correct or should it be `x` too?

Comment: Can you describe *in words* what condition you want to check? It seems like "both ``x`` and ``y`` must be one of ``"1"`` or ``"2"``.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your `f` is actually an `x`.

You can build a tuple of all admissible pairs of `x` and `y` and check if your pair is in that tuple:

```
x = "1"
y = "2"
(x, y) in (("1", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("2", "2"), ("2", "1"))
#True
```

In your specific example, it is enough to check if both variables have one of the predefined values:

```
x in "12" and y in "12"
#True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.

In case of true I would like to assign a variable for example variable_one = "Lorem ipsum" but it gives me an error because it is a loop

Comment: There is no loop anywhere on this page so far, neither in your question nor in my answer,